# Lookup data in a matrix table with two criteria from a table in another google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can't seem to get the right formula(s) to look up two criteria from a table (name and date) from another larger table in another google sheet. (Vlookup doesn't seem to work with multiple criteria and can't seem to get index/match or other functions to work correctly). Sample data shown in this Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iY843nTFW9N1jxgMJd82JHZfjI7hbRsBnZzCPLHianA/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Tried VLOOKUP and a couple versions using INDEX and MATCH, used QUERY...

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=makearray(counta(A2:A),counta(B1:Z1),lambda(r,c,+ifna(filter(filter(data!B2:Z,data!A2:A=index(A2:A,r)),data!B1:Z1=index(B1:Z1,,c)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That formula was a little complex for me so I play around and came up with just: =INDEX('Q6-Data'!$B$2:$V$12,MATCH($A4,'Q6-Data'!$A$2:$A$12,0),MATCH(B$3,'Q6-Data'!$B$1:$V$1,0)). All set now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDEX and MATCH twice, in order to find row and column indexes. Inserted into MAKEARRAY you can do the whole range with just one formula:

```
=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A),COUNTA(B1:1),LAMBDA(r,c,
  INDEX(data!B2:1000,
   MATCH(INDEX(A2:A,r),data!A2:A,0),
   MATCH(INDEX(B1:1,1,c),data!B1:1,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! That formula was a little complex for me so I play around and came up with just: =INDEX('Q6-Data'!$B$2:$V$12,MATCH($A4,'Q6-Data'!$A$2:$A$12,0),MATCH(B$3,'Q6-Data'!$B$1:$V$1,0)).  All set!

Comment: That's great! It's the same inside formula, but instead of making it an array, it's draggable